# AS3 do post through PHP without changing doted parameters

Tags: php, forms, actionscript-3

I am trying to communicate with Google Forms using AS3 and PHP. The problem is that when I pass parameters such `'entry.283123610'`, PHP changes these into `'entry_283123610'`. How can I prevent PHP from changing the post variables? This is the code I am currently using:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);    
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);    
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);    
ob_start();    
curl_exec ($ch);    
curl_close ($ch);    
$string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: I see no difference between entry 1 and entry 2 ?

Comment: sorry 'entry_283123610'

Comment: Where is the PHP? Is that something Google does or did you create the PHP?

Comment: I create it , the problem is that php do that for every thing not just my code , replacing dot with underscore , I'am looking for a way to prevent that

Comment: check this http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#81080

Comment: Well.. maybe show the bit of PHP code that does that? Maybe take it out or do you need it for something else?

Comment: Encyrpt it before sending to php. then have php decrypt and send it to google. Maybe try 64bit encode